# Remove last word from string

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to do something but can't remember/find the answer.  I have a list of city names from the Census Bureau and they put the city's type on the end which is messing up my `match()`.

I'd like to make this:

```
Middletown Township
Sunny Valley Borough
Hillside Village
```

into this:

```
Middletown
Sunny Valley
Hillside
```

Any suggestions?  Ideally I'd also like to know if there's a `lastIndexOf()` function in R.

Here's the data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  city = factor(c("Middletown Township", "Sunny Valley Borough", "Hillside Village"))
)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will work:

```
gsub("\\s*\\w*$", "", df1$city)
[1] "Middletown"   "Sunny Valley" "Hillside"
```

It removes any substring consisting of one or more space chararacters, followed by any number of "word" characters (spaces, numbers, or underscores), followed by the end of the string.

Comment: What if I want to get "Township, Borough, Village" i.e. the last word. And save it as a new variable?

Comment: You can use stringi package. Function name is stri_extract_last_words. You can provide this function a list of sentences and it will return list of last words in those sentences. However, it will not remove the last word from sentence, for removing purpose, we need the gsub command provided by Josh

Answer (score 19):

Here's a regexp that does what you need:

```
sub(df1$city, pattern = " [[:alpha:]]*$", replacement = "")
```

> [1] "Middletown"   "Sunny Valley" "Hillside"

That's replacing a substring that starts with a space, then contains only letters until the end of the string, with an empty string.

Comment: +1 this regex is better answer as it leaves single word intact.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `word()` in the stringr package like so:

```
df1 %>% mutate(city = word(city , 1  , -2))
```

The first argument (`1`) indicates that you're starting from the first word, and the second (`-2`) indicates that you're keeping everything up to the second last word.