# R (regex) - removing apartment, unit, and other words from end of address

Tags: r, regex, geolocation, pcre, street-address

I have a large dataset of addresses that I plan to geocode in ArcGIS (Google geolocating is too expensive). Examples of the addresses are below.

`9999 ST PAUL ST BSMT`

`GARRISON BL & BOARMAN AVENUE REAR`

`1234 MAIN STREET 123`

`1234 MAIN ST UNIT1`

ArcGIS doesn't recognize addresses that include units and other words at the end. So I want to remove these words so that it looks like the below.

`9999 ST PAUL ST`

`GARRISON BL & BOARMAN AVENUE`

`1234 MAIN STREET`

`1234 MAIN ST`

The key challenges include

1. `ST` is used both to abbreviate streets and indicate "SAINT" in street names.
2. Addresses end in many different indicators such as `STREET` and `AVENUE`
3. There are intersections (indicated with `&`) that might include indicators like `ST` and `AVENUE` twice.

Using R, I'm attempting to apply the `sub()` function to solve the problem but I have not had success. Below is my latest attempt.

`sub("(.*)ST","\\1",df$Address,perl=T)`

I know that many questions ask similar questions but none address this problem directly and I suspect it is relevant to other users.

Comment: you want to remove the last word from the each address ?

Comment: may be check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093931/r-remove-last-word-from-string

Comment: Are you trying to remove the last word? `sub("\\s*\\S+\\s*$", "", df$Address)`?

Comment: R uses PCRE, not Perl. Fixed tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I feel removing the last word should work for you, but just to be little safer, you can use this regex to retain what you want and discard what you don't want in safer way.

```
(.*(?:ST|AVENUE|STREET)\b).*
```

Here, `.*(?:ST|AVENUE|STREET)\b` captures your intended data by capturing everything from start in greedy manner and only stop when it encounters any of those words ST or AVENUE or STREET (i.e. last occurrence of those words), and whatever comes after that, will be discarded which is what you wanted. In your current case you only have one word but it can discard more than one word or indeed anything that occurs after those specific words. Intended data gets captured in group 1 so just replace that with `\1`

So instead of this,

```
sub("(.*)ST","\\1",df$Address,perl=T)
```

try this,

```
sub("(.*(?:ST|AVENUE|STREET)\b).*","\\1",df$Address,perl=T)
```

[See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/R3hj9k/1)

Comment: One slight modification is that R requires a double backlash on the `b` like so `sub("(.*(?:ST|AVENUE|STREET)\b).*","\\1",df$Address,perl=T)`. Otherwise, this is great. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. I missed that as I couldn't verify at my end as I never programmed in R. Glad to know my solution worked for you :)